# C# Unit Tests Failing Sporadically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a series of Visual Studio unit tests established for a C# command line parsing library I'm writing. Almost all the time when I run or debug all the tests (no parallel execution) they all pass.

But occasionally one of the tests will fail, generally with an index out of range exception from somewhere within the library (i.e., it's not the test code which is failing). It's not always the same test that fails, however.

I'm at a loss to understand what's going on or to figure out how to diagnose it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: The specifics are everything. This much I'll say with certainty - there's something non-deterministic about the test. Does the test actually automate a command window, maybe sending keys or something?

Comment: When it fails, is it ever during a single test run, or always seems to be when running a suite of tests, especially using the Test UI? (I.e. NUnit) It may be that the library being interfaced by the tests is not thread safe and some initialization interacting with the library is tripping while another test was running. For NUnit, the easiest way to ensure tests run across a single thread is to use the -workers=0 option.

Comment: "from somewhere within the library" If you're not sure where, maybe your unit tests need to be narrowed a little.